# WampServer 2.4 Can't Switch to MySQL 5.0.96

Tags: mysql, version, wamp, wampserver

I am using Wamp Server 2.4 to set up my local development sites. I want to use these Apache, PHP, and MySQL versions to match my live server configuration:

Apache 2.0.63

PHP 5.2.11

MySQL 5.0.96

MySQL 5.0.96 doesn't exist as an add-on package from the http://wampserver.com site so I had to download the MySQL 5.0.96 64-bit installer from Oracle's site and manually install it in the wamp bin folder.
After downloading it, I installed MySQL 5.0.96 to C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.0.96. Next, I ran the MySQL Instance Configuration program to generate the my.ini file. I then copied the wampserver.conf file from C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\ to C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.0.96.

Whenever I change the version of MySQL from 5.6.12 to 5.0.96 in the Wamp Manager tray, it turns orange and nothing starts.

Is there a missing service that needs to be installed or is there a problem in the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the solution. The problem was in the my.ini file. I used these settings from [here.](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/WampServer_HowTo.html)

```
[wampmysqld]
port = 3306
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
basedir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.0.96
log-error=c:/wamp/logs/mysql.log
datadir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.0.96/data
```

And now everything works!